# Confusion in understanding C++ standards

Tags: c++, standards

In C++98

> **12.6.2/4** : After the call to a constructor for class X has completed, if a member of X is neither specified in the constructor's *mem-initializers*, nor default-initialized, *nor initialized during execution of the body of the constructor*, the member has indeterminate value.

What does *nor initialized during execution of the body of the constructor* mean? Can a member be *initialized* inside the body of the constructor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*nor initialized during execution of the body of the constructor* is not correct IMHO.

The wordings have been changed in C++03 from *nor initialized* (in C++98) to *nor given a value*

> After  the  call  to  a  constructor  for  class X has  completed,  if  a  member  of X is  neither  specified  in  the constructor’s mem-initializers, nor default-initialized, nor value-initialized, **nor given a value** during execution of the body of the constructor, the member has indeterminate value.

Comment: I don't have a copy of C++03. From where can I get it?

Comment: IOW in the fragment "nor initialized during execution of the body of the constructor", the C++03 standard uses the word "initialized" in an informal way to mean "assigned a value".

Comment: @Bazinga : You can't get it for free.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, same in 4.1 "If the object to which the glvalue refers is not
an object of type T and is not an object of a type derived from T, or if the object is uninitialized, a program
that necessitates this conversion has undeﬁned behavior.".

Comment: @Bazinga: Amazon (and proabably others) have a dead-tree version , ISBN 978-0470846742.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually very simple.  class/struct members can include objects with default constructors, but if they don't, and you don't bother to give them a value in the initialiser list, nor set them within the body of the constructor, then basically the memory that they occupy - whatever was scrounged for them from the stack or heap - will still have old garbage in there, i.e. an indeterminate value.

Consider:

```
struct X
{
    X() : x1(1) { x2 = 2; }
    double x1, x2, x3;
    std::string x4;
};
```

Here, `x1` and `x2` are explicitly initialised by `X`'s constructor, and `x4` - being a `std::string` - is default constructed to be "" / length 0.  `x3`, however, could be anything - and shouldn't be read from until after it's been set (it's undefined behaviour and really could bite on some systems - consider that the bit pattern of the memory it occupies may not even be a valid value for a double, so reading from it might trigger some CPU exception/trap/interrupt).

Comment: I don't have a copy of C++03. From where can I get it?

Comment: Only the final draft is available for free - a quick google turns up many sources - e.g. http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/.  That's usually most convenient for me, but you can order an official copy of the final version for some small fee (20 or 30 dollars US)... I can't remember exactly where from.

Comment: @Bazinga: see [6.3] in http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/big-picture.html#faq-6.13 for instructions on getting a copy of the Standard.